# Background ZIndex in Windows Store application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I need to set an image background in my windows store application.

But when I do it like the code below shows, the image is covering all of the controls and I can see only this image not controls, how to solve this?

I can't see any kind of `ZIndex` property and setting `Canvas.ZIndex` does not work.

View:

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundSource}" />
</Grid.Background>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private string _backgroundSource;
    public string BackgroundSource
    {
        get { return _backgroundSource; }
        set { _backgroundSource = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => BackgroundSource); }
    }
```

and

```
   BackgroundSource = "Assets/Background/White.png";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies in how you have your visual tree organized. Without seeing your whole structure, one quick and easy way to achieve your goal would be to just rest your background piece behind everything else. For example;

If say you have a parent `Grid` currently like;

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundSource}" />
   </Grid.Background>

   <AllYourControls/>

</Grid>
```

You could fix it by doing something like this instead;

```
<Grid>

  <Grid>
     <Grid.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundSource}" />
     </Grid.Background>
  </Grid>

   <AllYourControls/>

</Grid>
```

or embed it like;

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundSource}" />
   </Grid.Background>

   <Grid>
      <AllYourControls/>
   </Grid>

</Grid>
```

There's multiple ways you could achieve your requirements with just a little organization in your tree and avoid any z-index or other hacky tricks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done like you say, but nothing going to change, controls are not visible, please have a look [here](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Win8/QuestionView.xaml)

Comment: I am a stupid guy, I have a backgorund with white color, so due this I was not able to see any controls, because these are also white ;/

Comment: Have to love those moments :)